# .partial files when checking out of TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I check out a solution from TFS a get a lot of .partial-files all over the project.

They are not on the TFS-Server, just on my PC. Sadly some of them prevent my solution from running and I always have to delete them manually. Can I somehow prevent this? Where do they come from?

Comment: My collegues get the same files. But I can't say if its a server or client issue. We all have new PCs with exactly the same set-up

Answer (score 1):

These files **exist in the local path of your workspace** but not added into source control. For the partial extension file, you can refer to [this page](http://fileinfo.com/extension/partial) for the meanings.

You can delete or ignore them directly. If you want to prevent it, you can also **change the local path of your workspace**, then you will not see the files.

Another option is creating a new workspace and using a different local path, then do a workspace mapping.